# SQL count all where condition ist not Fullfilled

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, count

I have a problem for which I have no solution. I have a table with 30,000 entries and a column of zip codes.

I now wanted to calculate the total for each individual ZIP code

```
SELECT
zipcode, count(zipcode)
FROM
testtable
Group by zipcode
```

Then ill get a result like this :

| Zip Codes | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| 90010 | 5025 |
| 90020 | 2503 |
| 90030 | 4565 |
| 90040 | 2134 |
| 12346 | 1 |
| 161681 | 16 |
| NULL | 15105 |
| 96874 | 1123 |

However, now I only want to add the ZIP codes in a special range and all those that do not correspond to this range to "Unknown" in one line.

The result should then look something like this:

| Zip Codes | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| 90010 | 5025 |
| 90020 | 2503 |
| 90030 | 4565 |
| 90040 | 2134 |
| unknown | 18000 |

Ill really have no idea how to solve this ? Do i need a type of temporary table ?

Thanks for your help and Time :)

Comment: Is a "special range" really a numeric range, e.g. `44000` through `44999`, or is it a list of values, e.g. `10580`, `10583` and `10588`? The first allows you to use simple comparisons while the second may be handled more gracefully with [`in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or an `outer join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` to map your original zipcode to a new value and then group and count that:

```
SELECT ISNULL(M.MappedZipcode, 'unknown') AS [Zip Codes], count(*) AS SUM
FROM testtable
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN zipcode BETWEEN '90000' AND '99999'
        THEN zipcode
        /* ELSE NULL is implied */
        END AS MappedZipcode
) M
GROUP BY M.MappedZipcode
ORDER BY [Zip Codes]
```

Depending on your source data, you may need to trim zip+4 values using the `LEFT()` function and may also need to cast the result to a string long enough to hold the "unknown" value.

Sample results:

| Zip Codes | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| 90010 | 1 |
| 90020 | 2 |
| 90030 | 3 |
| 90040 | 4 |
| 96874 | 1 |
| unknown | 6 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OZv3WKg9).

Side note: Best practice is to always store zip codes as text, not as integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help worked perfectly. But i have a hard time to understand why, this cross apply cant get in my head. Maybe when u have 2 minutes to spare, can u explain why this is ? If not its no Problem, thanks your Help

Comment: A `CROSS APPLY` is like a join to a subquery. For each row already selected, it will evaluate the subquery and will join the results back to the rest of the query. I typically use it in two situations: (1) If I with to define an intermediate calculation that I can then use (possibly multiple times) elsewhere in the query or (2) if i want to do a complex subquery (often a TOP 1 best match like "find the price record active on the specific order date") that depends on data already referenced earlier in the join.

Comment: The above usage is option #1. It is just a convenience that avoids duplicating the expression elsewhere. If you really wanted to, you could paste the entire `CASE` statement into the `SELECT` list and again into the GROUP BY - it would work, but is messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Just for completeness, the `CROSS APPLY` also has an `OUTER APPLY` counterpart that behaves like a `LEFT JOIN`. That is really only useful for th e#2 type scenarios, where the subquery might not return any results.

Comment: Slight correction to the above: "will join the results back to the rest of the query" should read "will join the results back to the current row".

Answer (score 1):

You could use UNION to group two different selects:

```
SELECT zipcode, count(zipcode)
  FROM testtable
  WHERE zipcode BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000
  GROUP BY zipcode
UNION
SELECT 'unknown', count(zipcode)
  FROM testtable
  WHERE zipcode NOT BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000;
```